# Calling method inside service activity in Android

Tags: java, android

How can i access method inside service activity
from my main activity i have a button to call method inside service activity
How can i do that.

MainActivity.java

```
button.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener (){
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
//frome here i wanna call the method inside service activity
}
});
```

Service.java

```
public mservice extends Service {
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind (Intent intent){
return null;
}
public void method (){
Toast.makeText (this,"call",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show ();
}
}
```

I created object from mservice class in MainActivity  like this

```
mservice s = new mservice ();
```

And when i try to call method it is just crashed

Comment: Check how to work with bound service in android. Check [this](https://www.truiton.com/2014/11/bound-service-example-android/)

Comment: I want just to access the method do you have another way.